Request for PHPWord Extension Compatible with PHP 5.5.3 and Yii1
I am currently working on an old application developed in Yii1 and running on PHP version 5.5.3. As part of a new requirement, I need to implement a feature to add watermarks to DOCX files generated by the application. After researching, I found that PHPWord is a suitable library for this task.
However, the latest versions of PHPWord require PHP 7 or later, which is not compatible with our current environment. Therefore, I am reaching out to the community to inquire if anyone has an older version of the PHPWord extension that is compatible with PHP 5.5.3.
Specifically, I am looking for a PHPWord extension that supports adding watermarks to DOCX files, especially on each page.
Any assistance or guidance on where to find such an extension would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!
